# How to make Cirrus CI use Java 17 to support Gradle 8

Tags: java-11, java-17, cirrus-ci, android-gradle-8

I wanted to upgrade my Android Studio project to use Gradle 8 and am using Cirrus CI for this project. However, when running the tests after having upgraded, Cirrus tells me that Java 17 is required for Gradle 8 and the current version on the CI is Java 11.

How can I make Cirrus use Java 17?

Here is my .cirrus.yml file:

```
container:
  image: cirrusci/android-sdk:30
  cpu: 4
  memory: 16G
  kvm: true

env:
  CC_TEST_REPORTER_ID: ENCRYPTED[!942125cb3ea65a81b33ed29fae738238f9060dfe3594af3e63b76f040c72b321905507ae5822965c7b031109cf07e3c8!]

check_android_task:
  name: Run Android tests
  install_emulator_script:
    sdkmanager --install "system-images;android-30;google_apis_playstore;x86"
  create_avd_script:
    echo no | avdmanager create avd --force
    --name emulator
    --package "system-images;android-30;google_apis_playstore;x86"
  start_avd_background_script:
    $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator
    -avd emulator
    -no-audio
    -no-boot-anim
    -gpu swiftshader_indirect
    -no-snapshot
    -no-window
    -camera-back none
  assemble_instrumented_tests_script: |
    chmod +x gradlew
    ./gradlew assembleDebugAndroidTest
  wait_for_avd_script:
    adb wait-for-device shell 'while [[ -z $(getprop sys.boot_completed) ]]; do sleep 3; done; input keyevent 82'
  disable_animations_script: |
    adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0.0
    adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0.0
    adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0.0
  prepare_codeclimate_script: |
    curl -L https://codeclimate.com/downloads/test-reporter/test-reporter-latest-linux-amd64 > ./cc-test-reporter
    chmod +x ./cc-test-reporter
    ./cc-test-reporter before-build
  screen_record_background_script:
    for n in $(seq 1 20); do adb exec-out screenrecord --time-limit=180 --output-format=h264 - > $n.h264; done
  check_script:
    ./gradlew check connectedCheck
  report_codeclimate_script: |
    export JACOCO_SOURCE_PATH=app/src/main/java/
    ./cc-test-reporter format-coverage ./app/build/reports/jacoco/jacocoTestReport/jacocoTestReport.xml --input-type jacoco
    ./cc-test-reporter upload-coverage
  lint_script:
    ./gradlew lintDebug
  always:
    wait_for_screenrecord_script: |
      pkill -2 -x adb
      sleep 2
    screenrecord_artifacts:
      path: "*.h264"
    android_lint_artifacts:
      path: ./app/build/reports/lint-results-debug.xml
      format: android-lint
    test_artifacts:
      path: "./app/build/test-results/**/*.xml"
      format: junit
    androidtest_artifacts:
      path: "./app/build/outputs/**/*.xml"
      format: junit
```

Sadly, all the Google searches I made came up empty.

Comment: Android SDK image in CirrusCI has been upgraded and Java 17 is included now!